# doctest QuickCheck – can I import QC instances only in doctests?

Tags: haskell, testing, quickcheck, doctest

I'm using [doctest](https://github.com/sol/doctest#readme), and like the fact that I can test non-exported functions from where they're defined:

```hs
module Foo (frobnicate) where

-- |
-- >>> randomInt = 42
-- True
randomInt :: Int
randomInt = 42
```

I've so far kept QuickCheck instances in the `test-suite` so the `library` doesn't depend on testing packages, but this means I can't run QuickCheck from doctests.

I can of course not use doctest and run QC from `test-suite`, but then I have to export each function that I want to test.

Is there a way to have doctests that use QC instances without having the main `library` depend on QC, (and without re-writing the instances in the doctest "repl")?

Comment: Can you not import modules in [doctest's setup code block](https://github.com/sol/doctest#setup-code)?

Comment: Not if they're not a part of the library, as far as I can tell. (Or, if I can, I'd like to know how!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of exactly what you are looking for:
https://github.com/sol/doctest#quickcheck-properties

Just add whatever imports you need in the setup code.

Comment: Say I have instances defined in `test/QCInstances.hs`, which is under cabal's `test-suite`, which depends on QuickCheck. If I now run `stack exec doctest src/Foo.hs` where Foo is under cabal's `library` I get `Could not find module ‘QCInstances’`.

Comment: Did you add the module and source directory (test) to the test-suite of the cabal file? Did you add the line `-- >>> import QCInstances` under the line `-- $setup` in the file with the doctests?

Comment: I've tried putting `QCInstances.hs` in `other-modules` of `test-suite` (cabal complains `Unknown field` if I try `exposed-modules` – I guess that's not supported for test-suites), but it still fails. It doesn't seem to matter if I try importing it in `-- $setup` or in the actual test – it still fails to import. And, I mean, this makes sense, why would doctest import modules from a test-suite when it's running the repl of the main library? Just like I can't import any test-suite modules when running the regular stack repl.

Comment: Try adding `-isrc test` to the parameters of doctest (not exactly sure how to do that with stack exec). Alternatively, you could use `stack test` and have a main file for your test suite that calls the doctest function: https://github.com/sol/doctest#cabal-integration

Comment: `stack exec doctest -- -isrc test src/Foo.hs` gives `test/QCInstances.hs:26:53: 
 Couldn't match expected type ‘QC.Gen MyType’ 
 with actual type ‘QuickCheck-2.8.2@Quick_AOTWGguKtKLBCUhkngiI4l:Test.QuickCheck.Gen.Gen
 a5 NB: ‘QC.Gen’ 
 is defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Gen’ 
 in package ‘QuickCheck-2.8.2@Quick_6TxL5Cx3o2p0HsyT59KWiD’` (and I had to delete some hs files from test first, o/w I get multiple Main's)